# Spectral norm for a truncated Hilbert matrix

Tags: approximation-theory

Let $T_{N}$ be the (Hilbert) matrix defined by $T_{N}(m,n)=\frac{1}{m-n}$ if $1\leq m,n \leq N$ and $m\neq n$ , and $ T_{N}(n,n)=0$ if $1\leq n \leq N$ .
It's well known that $\Vert T_{N}\Vert < \pi $.
In a work with O.Leveque we found that there are positive constants $a$ and $b$ such that
$\frac{a}{N} < \pi - \Vert T_{N}\Vert < \frac{b \log N}{N}$ , ($N>1$) .
Does somebody know the exact order for $ \pi - \Vert T_{N}\Vert$ ?